# Свернуть окно с помощью JQ вниз

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Привет. Подскажите есть ли функция которая скрывает блок вниз-направо и открывает вверх-налево? Если нет, то как можно реализовать? 
  Мне нужно скрывать и открывать iframe окно в котом будет чат.
P.S. Новенький в этом деле :) 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью проверки `display` и функции `animate`:

```js
$(function() {
  var chat = $('#chat');
  $('#openchat').click(function() {
    if(chat.css('display') == 'none'){
      chat.animate({width: 'show', height: 'show'});
    }else{
      chat.animate({width: 'hide', height: 'hide'});
    };
  });
});
```

```css
iframe#chat {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="openchat">Открыть чат</button>
<iframe id="chat" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Прижал блок к низу и с amimate() менял высоту и ширину :) Спасибо тема закрыта